# Phoenix Fallback action error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Elixir / Phoenix Framework noob here.

I am trying to add a new route that would resolve a string that I pass in as a URL segment.

router.ex

```
# Ping endpoint
scope "/", AppWeb do
 pipe_through :api # Use the default browser stack

 get "/:hash", ListnerController, :ping
end
```

listner_controller.ex

```
  def ping(conn, %{"hash" => hash}) do
    with {:ok, resp} <- Monitors.is_valid_hash(hash) do
      render(conn, "hash.json", %{:data => resp})
    end
  end
```

context - monitor.ex

```
  def is_valid_hash(hash) do
    hash
  end
```

I end up getting an error with the Fallback action. The code works fine as long as I don't use the with macro.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to return `{:ok, hash}` from `is_valid_hash`?

Comment: @Dogbert I was under the impression that return from `is_valid_hash` is mapped to `hash` in the `{:ok, hash}` map

Comment: @Dogbert thanks, I was returning the wrong format from the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is going to the fallback controller because your `with` pattern fails which ends up returning `hash` which is not a `Plug.Conn`. Returning a value that's not a `Plug.Conn` is forwarded to the fallback controller by Phoenix. You probably meant to return `{:ok, hash}` from `is_valid_hash`:

```
def is_valid_hash(hash) do
  {:ok, hash}
end
```